# Allow GET request on certain page

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have one page that I want to allow GET requests. Currently my htaccess file (unmodified) changes the URL when a GET request is made, creating a 404.

Example: `website.com/page?s=test` gets converted to `website.com/page/?s=test`

What can I do to allow the GET request and not allow the URL to be changed?

Comment: You're getting a 404 because of the `s` query var, which is the default WordPress search query var. You're basically querying for your page and searching for the string `test`, it'll only succeed if the page contains that string. The forward is unrelated, your original version is invalid, the version it redirects to is the correct way to append a query string to a page.

Comment: Thanks @Milo I didn't know s was the search query. Thanks a lot!